# Django widget for sensitive fields

Tags: django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I am working on a Django website that presents users a form to store their API keys and API secrets.

At the moment both fields are showing as `CharField` generated by `django-crispy-forms` so both their API key and API secrets are visible.

I would like a behaviour where by default the fields are showing ****** or ●●●●●● when not focused and revealing the content when focused.

I have tried making this field a `PasswordInput()` widget in `forms.py` with

> self.fields["my_field"].widget = forms.PasswordInput()

However this brings a couple of problems:

- Browsers consider the API keys and an API secrets as actual passwords and save them at the browser level which is not a desired behaviour
- When the field is focused, the contents of the fields are not shown. To make a change, the whole value has to be re-entered

Is creating a custom widget the only solution for this?

Comment: Do you need a backend solution for this, what about a front end solution?

Comment: Could do. As everything is managed by Django and django-crispy-forms for other fields at the moment I'd rather keep it at the backend level but if that's the only solution I'd give it a go.

Comment: I'm considering creating a custom Django widget that implements https://codepen.io/GBMahili/pen/pEvVeP